# Unable to set window position

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mdi

I'm using the http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/ library to handle MDI in my WPF application.

I've got a Canvas which contains a child container, which is to contain a number of small windows. I want the windows to be opened at position x=500, y=500. I have managed to achieve this with my current code, however strangely enough when the first window is opened, it is not show - i.e. the canvas remains blank. Then, once I add another window, both windows appear in the correct place.

Below I've pasted my XAML and the code which opens a new window in the canvas.

```
<Window x:Name="VisualQueryBuilderWindow" x:Class="QueryBuilder.VisualQueryBuilder"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mdi="clr-namespace:WPF.MDI;assembly=WPF.MDI"
    Title="Visual Query Builder" WindowState="Maximized" Closing="VisualQueryBuilderWindow_Closing">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TreeView">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,20,0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,5,0"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <TreeView DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
                  Name="tvSchema" 
                  AllowDrop="True" 
                  TreeViewItem.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="TreeViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
        </TreeView>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Name="tabQueryBuilder" Header="Query Builder">
                <Canvas Name="cnvsMain" Background="LightGray" AllowDrop="True" Drop="cnvsMain_Drop">
                    <mdi:MdiContainer Name="mainContainer" Background="LightGray">
                    </mdi:MdiContainer>
                </Canvas>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Name="tabResults" Header="Results"></TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
        TableWindow tableWindow = new TableWindow(tableName);

        MdiChild child = new MdiChild()
        {
            MaximizeBox = false,
            MinimizeBox = false,
            Resizable = true,
            ShowIcon = false,
            Title = tableName,
            Content = tableWindow.Content as UIElement //Opens new instance of my window class
        };

        mainContainer.Children.Add(child);
        child.Position = new Point(500, 500);
```

Please note that I've also tried setting the position inside the block of the MdiChild instantiation and it did not work there either.

**UPDATE:** I think it's also worth mentioning that my MdiContainer is placed within a tab, and I noticed that if I change tab and switch back to the one with the container, the window displays. Thus, could it be some sort of refreshing problem?

Comment: Just had a thought, what about calling `mainContainer.InvalidateArrange()` after setting the position?

Comment: @mlorbetske No luck either :(

Comment: @mlorbetske Added an update to the question

Comment: @DotNET Could you give us a short snippet of your exact control hierarchy ?

Comment: I've added all my XAML code to the question

Comment: Is the TableWindow.Content not Showing or the whole MdiChild not showing ? As i do not have your TableWindow class, I replaced it with a simple rectangle and can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: @Sisyphe The whole TableWindow isn't showing - and I also just realised that when I add more windows, some pieces of the window are hidden - switching tabs back and forth then makes the whole window display.

Comment: Could you come to WPF chat room ?

Comment: @Sisyphe I don't think it has anything to do with my TableWindow class as I have also tried removing the `Content` part and thus using a normal MdiWindow, however the problem was still there

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18287/discussion-between-dot-net-and-sisyphe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code before instantiating your TableWindow

```
mainContainer.SetBinding(WidthProperty, new Binding("ActualWidth") { Source = cnvsMain });
mainContainer.SetBinding(HeightProperty, new Binding("ActualHeight") { Source = cnvsMain });
```

You can also do it in the xaml :

```
<mdi:MdiContainer Name="mainContainer" Background="LightGray" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=cnvsMain}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=cnvsMain}">
                    </mdi:MdiContainer>
```

Actually it's not a very satisfying fix. There seems to be an issue with the library, it should update the container size when a child's position is set.